# How did /hw/ become spelled <wh>?

Tags: etymology

[*Why Do Languages Change?* (2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521546931) by R. L. Trask. p. 13.

> Changes in pronunciation can happen with considerable speed. Consider
>   /hw/. Historically, English had a number of words beginning with the sequence
>   of consonants /hw/, curiously spelled <wh> since the Middle Ages. This
>   sequence was pronounced very differently from plain /w/, and so *whine*
>   sounded different from *wine*, *whales* from *Wales*, *which* from *witch*, *where*
>   from *wear*, *wheel* from *weal*, and so on.

Why wasn't /hw/ spelled, more straightforwardly,  [<](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288707/how-do-you-show-words-surrounded-by-angle-brackets)hw>?

I'm uncertain if [this answer at ELU answers this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/84179/325696).

Answer (score 4):

It was originally written <hw>, such as in the Old English "hƿær/hwær" (where). It reversed its orthographic order in Middle English, but as far as I can tell there are no certain reasons for its doing so. One reason I've seen proposed is that because English employed many digraphs with <h>, Middle English speakers mistook <hw> to be a typo (or its pre-typing equivalent) and took it to be another h-digraph.